# Destructuring within array destructure

Tags: javascript, destructuring

Would it be possible to destructure within an array destructuring in the same line?

For example:

```
const array = [{a: 1, b: 2}, {c: 3, d: 4}]

const [ value1 ] = array;
const { a } = value1;
```

The following allows me to get the value `a`, but I was wondering if it would be possible to combine the 2nd and 3rd line together?

Answer (score 2):

Replace the `value1` with `{ a }` - it looks the same as declaring an object literal inside an array, except with destructuring:

```js
const array = [{a: 1, b: 2}, {c: 3, d: 4}]
const [{ a }] = array;
console.log(a);
```

(that said, I wouldn't recommend writing code like this most of the time, it looks a bit confusing)